# HTTP Digest Authentication Removed -Gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I have upgraded my gerrit application from 2.11.7 to 2.14.1 , but i am not getting https in my url. it looks like only http is present . In gerrit 2.14.1 release notes I can see HTTP Digest Authentication Removed .Does that mean we can't use https anymore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can continue using https.

Check the httpd.listenUrl option in the GERRIT_SITE/etc/gerrit.config file. Are you using "https" there?

Ex:

```
[httpd]
    listenUrl = proxy-https://localhost:8080/
```